# Blank Google Map In Android Application

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing android app which has google map to show. I have done very much part of coding but I am stuck to the problem of not getting google map display in m application. I have tried every method to make it work but no luck.

I am getting following error

## Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

I have created Google map api key with dubug & release mode but both keys are not working.

## AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.traqer"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<!-- Internet Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- Google Map Permissions -->
<permission
    android:name="com.example.traqer.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.traqer.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/splash"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dashboard" >
    </activity>
  

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="myapikey" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

## fragment_dashboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:apiKey="myapikey"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

## DashboardActivity.java

```
public class DashboardActivity extends Fragment implements Constants {

MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;

public DashboardActivity() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard,
            container, false);
    
    /** Google Map Code **/

    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it

    mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    map = mapView.getMap();
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    map.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(true);
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
    return rootView;
 }
}
```

After trying this I am getting blank google map with zoom control. Please suggest any way out any hint to solve this my problem.

Comment: Check : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: how you generate SHA-1 for google map key ?

Comment: @Haresh Chhelana. I read it before and tried to correct my code but     I am not getting any clue..??

Comment: I created SHA-1 with keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keys
tore "C:\Users\arun\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapView is deprecated, since a long time, use Google Map Api V2.

your map.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

//Activity to show map:

private GoogleMap googleMap;

```
if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
```

Do not forgot to enable Google Maps Api V2 service from your google console and to give your right Google Map Api key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I am tring to write googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(                  R.id.map)).getMap(); It giving error MapFragment cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/ visit this, here is the step by step explanation.